# How to declare a javascript 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

What is the proper way to declare a JavaScript 2d array? I've tried doing this

```
var matrix = new Array(new Array(2), new Array(2));
```

but it doesn't want to work. I am complete javascript beginner so if you can please help me out. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: FWIW: You don't "declare" arrays, because JavaScript is an untyped language. You create them. JavaScript also doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays. Insted, it has arrays of arrays. What you've done is one valid way to create a 2x2 "multidimensional" array. But see the linked question's answers for details.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to do so, but it can be easily achieved in one line:

```
const rows = 5;
const cols = 3;
const defaultValue = 0;
Array(rows).fill(null).map(_ => Array(cols).fill(defaultValue));
```